# Why does my image element stay the same while contents of all other divs change when clicking on previous, next or random buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

When I click on any of the buttons - namely: previous, next and random - the content of all divs change accordingly. The only exception is the image element, where the image remains the same. I don't know how to fix my code so as to make it display the image corresponding to the correct array I'm on. Everything else seems to work as it should be.

```js
// local reviews data
const reviews = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "susan smith",
    job: "web developer",
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg",
    text:
      "I'm baby meggings twee health goth +1. Bicycle rights tumeric chartreuse before they sold out chambray pop-up. Shaman humblebrag pickled coloring book salvia hoodie, cold-pressed four dollar toast everyday carry",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "anna johnson",
    job: "web designer",
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883409/person-2_np9x5l.jpg",
    text:
      "Helvetica artisan kinfolk thundercats lumbersexual blue bottle. Disrupt glossier gastropub deep v vice franzen hell of brooklyn twee enamel pin fashion axe.photo booth jean shorts artisan narwhal.",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "peter jones",
    job: "intern",
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg",
    text:
      "Sriracha literally flexitarian irony, vape marfa unicorn. Glossier tattooed 8-bit, fixie waistcoat offal activated charcoal slow-carb marfa hell of pabst raclette post-ironic jianbing swag.",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "bill anderson",
    job: "the boss",
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg",
    text:
      "Edison bulb put a bird on it humblebrag, marfa pok pok heirloom fashion axe cray stumptown venmo actually seitan. VHS farm-to-table schlitz, edison bulb pop-up 3 wolf moon tote bag street art shabby chic. ",
  },
];



const person = document.querySelector("#person-img");
const author = document.querySelector("#author");
const job = document.querySelector("#job");
const info = document.querySelector("#info");

const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev-btn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn");
const randomBtn = document.querySelector(".randomBtn");



let number = 0;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const item = reviews[number]
  person.src = item.img;
  author.innerHTML = item.name;
  job.innerHTML = item.job;
  info.innerHTML = item.text;
})

function showPerson(person) {
  const item = reviews[person]
  person.src = item.img;
  author.innerHTML = item.name;
  job.innerHTML = item.job;
  info.innerHTML = item.text;

}


// show next person
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  number++
  if(number > reviews.length - 1) {
    number = 0
  }
  showPerson(number)
})



prevBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  number--
    if(number < 0) {
      number = reviews.length - 1;
    }

  showPerson(number)
})

randomBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * reviews.length)
  showPerson(number)
})
```

```css
/*
=============== 
Fonts
===============
*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:400,700&display=swap");

/*
=============== 
Variables
===============
*/

:root {
  /* dark shades of primary color*/
  --clr-primary-1: hsl(205, 86%, 17%);
  --clr-primary-2: hsl(205, 77%, 27%);
  --clr-primary-3: hsl(205, 72%, 37%);
  --clr-primary-4: hsl(205, 63%, 48%);
  /* primary/main color */
  --clr-primary-5: hsl(205, 78%, 60%);
  /* lighter shades of primary color */
  --clr-primary-6: hsl(205, 89%, 70%);
  --clr-primary-7: hsl(205, 90%, 76%);
  --clr-primary-8: hsl(205, 86%, 81%);
  --clr-primary-9: hsl(205, 90%, 88%);
  --clr-primary-10: hsl(205, 100%, 96%);
  /* darkest grey - used for headings */
  --clr-grey-1: hsl(209, 61%, 16%);
  --clr-grey-2: hsl(211, 39%, 23%);
  --clr-grey-3: hsl(209, 34%, 30%);
  --clr-grey-4: hsl(209, 28%, 39%);
  /* grey used for paragraphs */
  --clr-grey-5: hsl(210, 22%, 49%);
  --clr-grey-6: hsl(209, 23%, 60%);
  --clr-grey-7: hsl(211, 27%, 70%);
  --clr-grey-8: hsl(210, 31%, 80%);
  --clr-grey-9: hsl(212, 33%, 89%);
  --clr-grey-10: hsl(210, 36%, 96%);
  --clr-white: #fff;
  --clr-red-dark: hsl(360, 67%, 44%);
  --clr-red-light: hsl(360, 71%, 66%);
  --clr-green-dark: hsl(125, 67%, 44%);
  --clr-green-light: hsl(125, 71%, 66%);
  --clr-black: #222;
  --ff-primary: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --ff-secondary: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  --transition: all 0.3s linear;
  --spacing: 0.1rem;
  --radius: 0.25rem;
  --light-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --dark-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  --max-width: 1170px;
  --fixed-width: 620px;
}
/*
=============== 
Global Styles
===============
*/

*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: var(--ff-secondary);
  background: var(--clr-grey-10);
  color: var(--clr-grey-1);
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--clr-grey-5);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4 {
    line-height: 1;
  }
}
/*  global classes */

/* section */
.section {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

.section-center {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .section-center {
    width: 95vw;
  }
}
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

/*
=============== 
Reviews
===============
*/
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.underline {
  height: 0.25rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background: var(--clr-primary-5);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: var(--fixed-width);
}
.review {
  background: var(--clr-white);
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  box-shadow: var(--light-shadow);
  transition: var(--transition);
  text-align: center;
}
.review:hover {
  box-shadow: var(--dark-shadow);
}
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
#person-img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.img-container::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f10e";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  background: var(--clr-primary-5);
  color: var(--clr-white);
}
.img-container::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--clr-primary-5);
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.25rem;
  right: -0.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#author {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}
#job {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--clr-primary-5);
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}
#info {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
.prev-btn,
.next-btn {
  color: var(--clr-primary-7);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  transition: var(--transition);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prev-btn:hover,
.next-btn:hover {
  color: var(--clr-primary-5);
}
.random-btn {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  background: var(--clr-primary-10);
  color: var(--clr-primary-5);
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  transition: var(--transition);
  border-color: var(--clr-primary-5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.random-btn:hover {
  background: var(--clr-primary-5);
  color: var(--clr-primary-1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Starter</title>
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
    />

    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>review project</h1>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <img src="" id="person-img" alt="">
    <div id="author"></div>
    <div id="job"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>

    <button class="prev-btn" type="button">Previous</button>
    <button class="next-btn" type="button">Next</button>
    <button class="randomBtn" type="button">randomBtn</button>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `showPerson` function

you are using the same name for the img references and the index of the array

change

```
function showPerson(person) {
  const item = reviews[person]
  person.src = item.img; //person is a number
  author.innerHTML = item.name;
  job.innerHTML = item.job;
  info.innerHTML = item.text;

}
```

into

```
function showPerson(index) {
  const item = reviews[index]
  person.src = item.img;
  author.innerHTML = item.name;
  job.innerHTML = item.job;
  info.innerHTML = item.text;

}
```